Apache2 use same DocumentRoot (Codebase) apart from different config.php file per VirtualHost
I have two Virtual Host on different ports. At the moment they have two separate DocumentRoot. BUT the DocumentRoot is actually the same (CodeBase) only the config.php file in it defines to which Database the VirtualHost points.
For the sake of keeping it together and only maintain one code base I would like to have only one DocumentRoot = Code Base
but if you come over VirtualHost with port 8181 i want to serve another config.php than if you come over port 8182
How can this be achieved?
Information:

I have a proxy (Nginx Proxy Manager in place who sorts out the DNS adresses to the local ports 8181 and 8182

the databases are EADB-wkz and EADB-swa -> the User and Passwort to access the DBs are the same, just the DB-name ist different per Solution / Port

The sites-enabled configuration are as this at the moment:


Listen 8181

<VirtualHost *:8181>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/eadb-wkz
    
    ErroLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

Listen 8182

<VirtualHost *:8182>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/eadb-swa
    
    ErroLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

I only set up the two virtual hosts but now need to maintain the copied codebase which actually only differs in config.php
i tried looking into possibilities to dynamically exchange just one file depending on VirtualHost but couldnt find anything

Ok - i kind of solved it with symlinks.
So I have one Folder where I have the code base on which I work on the code. From there I symlink these folders into the "DocumentRoot" of every Customer and only have a dedicated config.php within these customer folders
